# Can I replace void* in callback parameters with the proper type if known ahead of time directly in C++?

Tags: c++

Let's say I'm using a C library that uses callbacks (for example curl).

```
static size_t my_callback(void *buffer, size_t sz, size_t n, void *f)
{
  /// ... Do something
}

curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_callback);

std::string toto("my string");

curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &toto);
```

If I know the type of one of the `void*` callback parameters can I just do this?

```
// Replace last void* parameter with std::string* because the type is known ahead of time
static size_t my_callback(void *buffer, size_t sz, size_t n, std::string *f)
{
  /// ... Do something
}
```

Or do I have to keep the `void*` and do the cast manually?

Comment: If it is guaranteed that a `string*` will be passed, then yes use that as type of corresponding parameter.

Comment: Also note that a function pointer cannot be portably converted to `void*`

Comment: If you use the prototype `size_t my_callback(void *buffer, size_t sz, size_t n, std::string *f)` then I suspect the compiler will complain that `my_callback` has the wrong type in the call `curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_callback)`.  Hence I suspect the cast from `void *` to `std::string *` needs to be performed explicitly in `my_callback`.

Comment: It'd require `reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void*, size_t, size_t, void*)>(&my_callback)` ... and I don't think that's ok.

Comment: Best thing to do is to provide an extra wrapper function that does the casting and calls your C++ function with the proper parameters or find a C++ library (or C++ binding for libcurl).

Comment: I don't understand your question, as it can easily be answered by trying, so I'm wondering if there's a hidden meaning on top of that.

Comment: Regarding my own comment above: I just looked in the curl source code and internally, if `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is not set, curl itself does the C equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast` by assigning `fwrite` to the pointer (via a cast). Nasty :-)

Comment: Regarding what @stefaanv said: In C++ it's very common to use C style callbacks and to provide `this` as the `userdata`. The callback function (a `static` member function) can then cast the pointer to the proper type and call the appropriate member function on the object.

Comment: C++ standard section 7.6.1.9 `[expr.reinterpret.cast]`: *The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type (9.3.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in
the definition of the function is undefined*. So the answer is no.

Comment: @Homer512 Sounds like a proper answer. Would get my vote!

Comment: It'd only work if you can change the signature for all the code involved, including the **C library** — which won't know anything about `std::string`.

Comment: @Eljay It does work though and the cast I mentioned above isn't even needed. `curl_easy_setopt` is a variadic function so you could supply _anything_ as the parameter to the option.  `curl_easy_setopt` will pick a `curl_write_callback` (a function pointer of the correct type) from the `va_list` when `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is used and it has no idea that the function pointer there is actually pointing to a function where the fourth argument is not a `void*`.  The `void* userdata` curl stores is supplied to the callback function that picks it up as a `std::string*`. UB, but works. :)

Comment: Since curl is relying on this to work internally too, I think it will actually work on all platforms where curl exists.

Comment: @TedLyngmo until it suddenly stops working, and curl becomes horribly broken on that platform

Comment: @Caleth Yes, exactly. One of the worlds most used libraries suddenly goes bonkers :-) Perhaps it has `#ifdef`s to check so that it wont even build on such platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. But you can get close. First, the callback with the type that you want:

```
static size_t my_callback(void *buffer, size_t sz, std::string *f)
{
  /// ... Do something
}
```

And then you wrap the function in a non-capturing lambda that does the necessary cast:

```
curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
   +[](void *buffer, size_t sz, size_t n, void *f) {
       return my_callback(buffer, sz * n, static_cast<std::string*>(f));
   });
```

Conveniently, the non-capturing lambda object is convertible to a function pointer that is needed to pass along. However, since `curl_easy_setopt` is a macro that invokes a variadic function, the conversion does not happen automatically. We have to use another trick: the unary `+` forces the conversion to a function pointer.